# Reference children css in js

Tags: javascript, css

I have a parent tag as `#parallax-bg1` and I am able to reference them as whole in js. But how do I refer its children? As in  `#bg1-1` and `#bg1-2` each?

So that instead of changing the whole parent #parallax-bg1, I can set values to each of its childrens #bg1-1 and #bg1-2.

main.css

```css
#parallax-bg1 {
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    /*left: 50%; /* align left edge with center of viewport */
    top: 0;
    width: 2200px;
    margin-left: -270px; /* move left by half element's width */
}
#bg1-1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    left: 270px;
    width: 1920px;
    height: 1080px;
}
#bg1-2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    left: 1990px;
    width: 1920px;
    height: 1080px;
    }
```

js

```js
function Scroll(){
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();

    $('#parallax-bg1').css('left',(0-(scrolled*.4))+'px'); //parent

}
```

Comment: Any reason why you cannot access it directly like this `$('#bg1-1')` ? Since the selector is id you will not have a duplicate.

Comment: @kiranvj I tried it, was not able to :/

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla Javascript

```
document.querySelector('#parallax-bg1 #bg1-1').style.left = `0-(${scrolled}*.4))px`
```

Jquery

```
$('#parallax-bg1 #bg1-1').css('left',(0-(scrolled*.4))+'px'); //parent
```